# Is it possible to add a CustomUser(AbstractUser) to a modelAdmin menu?

Tags: wagtail

My app has a customed User. It works fine with the standard settings menu: http://localhost:8888/admin/users/

But it I create a menu with a ModelAdmin class, it gives a wrong url: http://localhost:8888/admin/users/user/

```
from .models import User

class UserAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = User
```

The actual url: */admin/users/user/* raises a *ValueError*

```
ValueError at /admin/users/user/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8888/admin/users/user/
Django Version:     2.0.9
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

    invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user'

    Exception Location:     /home/lm/proyectos/sebusca/sebusca_django/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 947
    Python Executable:  /home/lm/proyectos/sebusca/sebusca_django/env/bin/python

...

Local vars
    Variable    Value
    args        ('user',)
    kwargs      {}
    request     <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/users/user/'>
    view_func    <function edit at 0x7f0948213f28>
```

My User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    centro = models.ForeignKey('CentroEducativo', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class CentroEducativo(models.Model):
    pass
```

It is the user model that actualy returns

> django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong URL"? Is the view at `/admin/users/user/` broken (if so: please tell us what the error is), or is it just not the URL you wanted?

Comment: The url  /admin/users/user/ raises a ValueError. See the reedited entry

Comment: You import your user form `.models`. Can you share your user model? Is that the same User model as you get from `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model`?
`

Comment: Yes, @allcaps. The model works fine. I think the issue is only the url

Comment: I edited the question, @gasman.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMorillas I found a previous report of this issue, with a suggested fix: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4713#issuecomment-410036098 (Not adding this as an answer, as I haven't confirmed it myself)

Comment: I've tested it and it seems to work fine. Thanks, @gasman. I'll write an anwer later.